# Native library not working properly on detached Expo App (Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'SystemSettingNative.setVolume'))

Tags: react-native, expo, detach

I have just detached an expo project to be able to set the global volume of my phone (I have never done it before), react-native link seems to work ok , but when I try to use the *setVolume* method from the SystemSetting library

I get a error:

[image: Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'SystemSettingNative.setVolume')]

Am I doing something wrong? (I have also tried to link the library manually with no luck)

```
import SystemSetting from 'react-native-system-setting';

export default class DispositivoGenerico extends React.Component{

  MudaVolume(InputValue){
  var oldMax = 255;
  var oldMin = 0;
  var newMax = 100;
  var newMin = 0;
  var oldRange = oldMax - oldMin
  var newRange = newMax - newMin

  var newValue = ((InputValue - oldMin) * newRange / oldRange) + newMin;

  SystemSetting.setVolume(newValue);
  this.props.OnValueChangeSlider(InputValue);
```